# Emberjs form view submit action

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to generate a an ember action with a view

```
   Training.NewEntryView = Ember.View.extend
        templateName: 'new_entry'
        tagName: 'form'
        submit: ->
                @get('controller').send('addEntry')
                false
```

The form is rendered properly but when I press the submit button the page is reloaded, instead of executing the action.

Comment: Could you provide more information and code? And ideally put together a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution preparing the code on JSbin.com
http://jsbin.com/ceqik/2/